# Fire Function if Button or Other Button Is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is probably really obvious, but because it's hard to clearly describe, I can't find anything through searching.

I want to do something where if a user clicks on any of several buttons, one event gets triggered. Is this possible? This is what I've tried, but it doesn't appear to work:

`$("#button1" || "#button2").click(function() {alert("example")});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#button1, #button2").click(function() {alert("example")});
```

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: Perfect, I'll accept as soon as it'll let me. Knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 3):

Just apply the handler to all the buttons.

```
$("#button1,#button2").click(...
```

Using the `,` creates a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), and because of jQuery's *"implicit iteration"*, it will add the `click()` handler to all matched elements.

---

That said, if there are many buttons, usually it's nicer to give all the buttons a common class.

```
$(".my_buttons").click(...
```

Comment: It's about 2-3 items per function. I'm working with a stupid WordPress plugin that I don't have much control over so I can't really use custom classes like that anyway. Thanks though.